# Recuperar Item jSON - API Facebook

Tags: php, json, facebook

Estou trabalhando com a **API do Facebook** e estou tentando recuperar um item do jSON, mas não estou conseguindo.

Primeiramente esse é o jSON que me é retornado do **Graph Facebook API**.

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "message": "Boa Tarde!",
         "id": "**********************************",
         "created_time": "2015-09-24T19:10:13+0000"
         "from": {
             "name": "Diego Souza",
             "id": "**************************"
          },
      },
      {
         "name": "Mensagem",
         "id": "**********************************",
         "created_time": "2015-08-17T19:17:50+0000"
      },
      {
         "name": "Mensagem",
         "id": "**********************************",
         "created_time": "2015-07-17T13:06:12+0000"
      },
      {
         "name": "Mensagem",
         "id": "**********************************",
         "created_time": "2015-07-17T12:47:06+0000"
      },
      {
         "name": "Mensagem",
         "id": "**********************************",
         "created_time": "2015-07-17T12:41:41+0000"
      }
   ],
}
```

Estou fazendo esse código:

```
# Posts Facebook
$authID         = "***************";
$authToken      = "***************";
$urlFace        = "https://graph.facebook.com/$authID/feed?fields=name,message&access_token=$authToken";
$jsonDados      = file_get_contents($urlFace);
$jsonObject     = json_decode($jsonDados, TRUE);

foreach ($jsonObject['data'] as $key => $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
```

E está me retornando assim:

```
Array
(
    [message] => Boa Tarde ! :)
    [from] => Array
        (
            [name] => Diego Souza
            [id] => **************************
        )

    [id] => **************************
    [created_time] => 2015-09-24T19:10:13+0000
)
Array
(
    [name] => Mensagem
    [id] => **********************************
    [created_time] => 2015-08-17T19:17:50+0000
)
Array
(
    [name] => Mensagem
    [id] => **********************************
    [created_time] => 2015-07-17T13:06:12+0000
)
Array
(
    [name] => Mensagem
    [id] => **********************************
    [created_time] => 2015-07-17T12:47:06+0000
)
Array
(
    [name] => Mensagem
    [id] => **********************************
    [created_time] => 2015-07-17T12:41:41+0000
)
```

### O que eu preciso

Nesse caso eu gostaria de pegar apenas mensagens postadas pelos usuários, que seria o **array** `message` no **jSON**.

Eu tentei isso:

```
foreach ($jsonObject['data'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $var)
        echo $var;
}
```

Mas me retornou todas as mensagens ao invés do que está em `message`.
O complicado é que ele monta vários arrays. E eu preciso dos arrays que contenham apenas o `message`. Nesse caso que postei tem apenas um post de usuário na página do Facebook. Vai ter mais.

Preciso dos arrays que tenham apenas o `message`. Só me complica esse Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da forma que você está fazendo, está dizendo para acessar todos os *values* de *data*. Se quer exibir somente a chave *message*, acessa-a:

```
foreach ($json['data'] as $data) {
    print($data['message']);
}
```

Caso queira/prefira, você pode verificar se no array atual contém a chave *message* e atribuí-la em uma variável:

```
$messages = array();

foreach ($json['data'] as $data) {
   if(array_key_exists('message', $data)){
      $messages[$data['id']]['message']     = $data['message'];
      $messages[$data['id']]['from_name']   = $data['from']['name'];
      $messages[$data['id']]['from_id']     = $data['from']['id'];
   }
}

print_r($messages);
```

Resultará em:

```
Array
(
    [******************] => Array
        (
            [message] => Boa Tarde!
            [from_name] => Diego Souza
            [from_id] => 100002341316240
        )
)
```

Editado conforme [edição #4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/89816/4) da pergunta.

Comment: Não sei se esse é o caminho. `message` não é um `array`. Quando faço esse código me retorna erro: `Undefined index: message`.

Comment: Sim, não é um array, é a chave de um sub array retornado do json. Ele retorna o erro pois nem todos os sub array tem a chave *message*. Eu adicionei uma opção a mais na resposta, assim você pode verificar antes.

Comment: Eu dei uma mudada na recuperação de dados, tive que acrescentar o `from`. Agora preciso recuperar o `message` e o seu `from -> name`. E ignorar os outros `arrays` que não contenham `messages`.

Comment: O que postei deu certo? Vou modificá-lo com base no que você editou agora.

Comment: Sim, deu certo. Obrigado. O problema mesmo está em recuperar o `from`.

Comment: Editei a resposta conforme a edição #4 da sua pergunta. Verifique se é isso que você precisa.

Comment: É exatamente o que eu preciso mesmo. Obrigado, funcionou. Agora eu vou pesquisar como fazer uma randomização desse `array` para eu mostrar apenas 1 item a cada refresh.

Comment: Você pode dar um `shuffle($messages)` e depois um `array_slice($messages, 1);` Há outras formas também.